# Which one is good practice about python formatted string?

Tags: python, file

Suppose I have a file on `/home/ashraful/test.txt`. Simply I just want to open the file. 
Now my question is:

which one is good practice?

**Solution 1:**

```
dir = "/home/ashraful/"
fp = open("{0}{1}".format(dir, 'test.txt'), 'r')
```

**Solution 2:**

```
dir = "/home/ashraful/"
fp = open(dir + 'test.txt', 'r')
```

The both way I can open file.

Thanks :)

Comment: When it comes to combining strings in Python in general, I would say that go with what is more readable, a that is one principle of Python. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/ In this case it would be the second one if there weren't those better options to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

instead of concatenating string use `os.path.join` `os.path.expanduser` to generate the path and open the file. (assuming you are trying to open a file in your home directory)

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'test.txt')) as fp:
    # do your stuff with file
```

Comment: I was just about to type that. May be you can include one line of sample code to make it more complete?

Comment: If the file you're opening is expected to be in the same directory as the script opening it, `open('test.txt')` is the best thing to do.  Sometimes things are only in my home directory because that's where I started working on them, and they get moved...

Comment: Thanks a lot. now it make sense.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam glad it helped.

Comment: @cco: No, that's not the solution. `open('test.txt')` will try to open the file in the current working directory which doesn't have to be the same directory where the script is in. You can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the directory of the script.

Comment: You are, obviously, correct in what you say.  What I really should have said is that in the (infrequent) case that I use fixed filenames, I find it less surprising to have scripts look in the current directory than in the script's directory.  My suggestion does that.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to open files/directories, as others have mentioned, you should use the `os.path.join()` method. However, if you want to format string in Python -- as your question title suggests -- then your first approach should be preferred. To quote from [PEP 310](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/):

> This PEP proposes a new system for built-in string formatting
>       operations, intended as a replacement for the existing '%' string
>       formatting operator.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to us os.path.join() here

```
import os.path

#…
dir = '/home/ashraful/'
fp = open(os.path.join(dir, 'test.txt'), 'r')
```